# why exponential term neglected in equation?

Tags: convolution, linear-systems, frequency-response, stability

[image]

---

where does that exponential term gone, is this because it is a constant term or it has to do something with stablity?

Comment: Lol really? Imagine it's a vector with length 1, no matter the angle it will always be 1. 

Comment: @gurghet be nice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The magnitude of that complex exponential is 1. Recall from complex algebra: any complex number can be expressed as $z = r e^{j \phi}$ where $|z|=r$ is its magnitude and $\arg z = \phi$ is the argument. Using this note that

$$
|e^{-j\Omega \lambda}| = 1
$$

which is why it "disappeared".

Answer (score 2):

Simply because, when $C$ is a real number, $|e^{jC}|=1$. Here, $C=\Omega\lambda$, apparently real numbers.

Another interpretation is: if you change the phase of a signal (like a mere time-shift), it turns into a constant modulus in the Fourier domain, and provides some invariance, used for instance recently in data classification with [Invariant Scattering Convolution Networks](http://www.di.ens.fr/data/scattering/).